# When QuerySnapshot will be null in addSnapshotListener in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

After updating `Firestore` library I noticed that `QuerySnapshot?` become nullable.
I don't know when snapshot can be null and if it's safe to use `!!` operator or I need to handle the null case.

ie. is it safe to use this code?

```
fireStoreRef
        .addSnapshotListener(this) { snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
            if (e == null) {
                snapshot!!.toObject()
            }else{
                // handle error
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuerySnapshot will be null only if `FirebaseFirestoreException` is not null.

So it is safe to use `!!` operator, if you are checking for the error is null like the examples in the docs.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/EventListener)

> onEvent will be called with the new value or the error if an error
>   occurred. **It's guaranteed that exactly one of value or error will be
>   non-null.**